# How to properly use Intent and Uri data with AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-intent, android-asynctask, uri

I need to use an AsyncTask to download an image from the web.  I would like to do this using an intent that can be thrown back to my MainActivity.  The code below does download the image HOWEVER I must press the back button once in order to actually see the image.  The Uri I am passing in is the data I need for the download method to do it's work.

Here is my question:
How can I pass a Uri into an AsyncTask, properly form an intent to start the download method, and return to the calling activity with that intent?

Also please do not mention Picasso, I specifically need to use AsyncTask.

```
   private class DownloadAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Uri, Void, Intent>{

    private Uri  mUri;

    public DownloadAsyncTask(Uri uri) {

        this.mUri = uri;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {

        Toast.makeText(DownloadActivity.this, "Beginning download...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    };

    @Override
    protected Intent doInBackground(Uri... params) {

        Log.i(TAG, "in doInBackground()");
        Intent i = new Intent(DownloadActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
        //set the intent data to the result of the method that actually downloads this image
        i.setData(DownloadTools.downloadImage(DownloadActivity.this, mUri));
        setResult(RESULT_OK, i);

        return i;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute() {

        Toast.makeText(DownloadImageActivity.this, "Finished Download.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        finish();
    };
}
```

MainActivity callback:

```
    @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode,
                                int resultCode,
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == DOWNLOAD_IMAGE_REQUEST) {

            //use the path found in the data to open the image in the gallery.
            String address = data.getData().toString();
            Intent galleryIntent = makeGalleryIntent(address);

            // Start the Gallery Activity.
            startActivity(galleryIntent);
        }
    }
```

Comment: How are you using the data from the intent in your MainActivity? Including that code may be useful.

Comment: Can you post the main activity past that deals with this? Are you starting activity with result and pulling the image in the on result method?

Comment: Good call thanks guys.  I have added the code.

Comment: first of all use `data.getData().getPath()` second of all why do you do declare a public String or Uri variable in a singleton and assign it and retrieve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you trying to do this approach using an intent?
From what i understand you want to start an AynTask and pass back the result to the main activty, isn't it? To achieve this you should use and interface to implement the CallBack.

```
public interface I_CallBackTask {

public void getResultFromAsynTask(String result);

}

private class DownloadAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Uri, Void, String>{



private Uri  mUri;
public I_CallBackTask callback;

public DownloadAsyncTask(Uri uri) {

    this.mUri = uri;
}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {

    Toast.makeText(DownloadActivity.this, "Beginning download...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
};

@Override
protected String doInBackground(Uri... params) {

    //Do your background code for download here

    //return the result of your download: if is an image it could be byte[], ...


    return resultfrombackground;
}
//result same type as resultfrombackground

protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

    callback.getResultFromAsynTask(result);


};
}

//your main activity

public YourActivity implements CallBackTask{
// your Activity 


 //your code .....


//On your main activity start the asyntask and pass your uri in the parameter
DownloadAsyncTask asyntask = new DownloadAsyncTask(yourUri);
asyncTask.execute();
asyncTask.callback = this;



 @Override
public void getResultFromAsynTask(String result){
// do what you need with the result and start the new activity
}


}
```

Comment: I do need to access AsyncTask data but I am trying to integrate this change from a handler to AsyncTask without having to rewrite anything else and in order to do that I have to interact with other code using an intent.

Comment: Actually this can still work with intent data.  Rather than calling the intent from AsyncTask I can use data in AsyncTask to call an intent elsewhere.  Thanks for this info, this worked just fine.